# What different ways are there to do a (simple) SQL-injection?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

I am playing around with computer security on a "challenge-site" to get some knowledge in the area. One task is to do a SQL-injection is to "Enter the Id of the customer you want to look up". What I've done is to send:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerId = 1 OR 1 = 1;
```

From what I can find online this should work since 1 = 1, but for some reason it doesn't, I get "No results" as an output. Are there any more ways to do a SQL-injection for this purpose?

Comment: did you send the entire query as shown here?

Comment: Probably you are expected to enter `1` as Id, but you get this query by entering `1 OR 1 = 1` possibly followed by a `--`

Comment: See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection

Answer (score -1):

You can use sqlmap, this is an open source penetration testing tool that automates the process of detecting and exploiting SQL injection flaws and taking over of database servers.